# Java EE 7: How-to inject an EJB into a WebSocket ServerEndpoint?

Tags: dependency-injection, websocket, ejb, java-ee-7, tyrus

To sum up my failing project: My `@ServerEndpoint` class is packaged in a WAR together with the beans.xml file. My WAR in turn is packaged in a EAR and this EAR file is what gets deployed to a GlassFish 4 server that internally use Tyrus.

### Should it be possible?

The WebSocket [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/websocket-1_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html) says:

> Websocket endpoints running in the Java EE platform must have full
>   dependency injection support as described in the CDI specification.
>   Websocket implementations part of the Java EE platform are required to
>   support field, method, and constructor injection using the
>   javax.inject. Inject annotation into all websocket endpoint classes,
>   as well as the use of interceptors for these classes.

The only thing I can understand of this paragraph is that injecting an Enterprise JavaBean into a WebSocket should be no rocket science. However, for me, whatever I do, it fails to work. I feel that most intuitively one should only need to prefix a server endpoint instance field with the `@EJB` or `@Inject` annotation, but no one of these annotations work. The variable will be null.

### Already a known problem?

**One Internet [source](https://blogs.oracle.com/brunoborges/entry/integrating_websockets_and_jms_with)** says a bit cryptically that "due to a bug" he must use constructor injection. I saw that he had added the annotation `@Named` to the server endpoint. I used the famous copy paste pattern and did exactly what he did, with and without the @Named annotation, and it still don't work. In fact, my `@Inject` annotated constructor is never even called!

**The Tyrus [user guide](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.3.3/user-guide.html)** says that one can mix together anyone of the famous session bean declaration annotations with the server endpoint (`@Stateful`, `@Stateless` and `@Singleton`). So I did, still the injection fails to happen. It doesn't matter if I use the annotation @Inject or @EJB.

And that is strange, because **the book [Java EE 7 Developer Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849687943)** claims to have a working example on page 27 and page 28 based on the same approach. Author Peter Pilgrim annotates his server endpoint `@Stateless`. He then uses `@Inject` to do the injection. He says:

> In Java EE 7 we must also declare [our server endpoint] as a stateless
>   EJB with @Stateless in order to inject [another EJB] as a dependency.
>   (This is a consequence of Java for WebSocket 1.0 specification.) Note
>   that we can use @javax.annotation.Inject from CDI.

Okay so he says we **must** use a @Stateless annotation, and "notes" that one can use @Inject. For me, it sounds utterly strange that we "must" use a @Stateless annotation on a server endpoint which according to the specification, is everything else than stateless (!). I've read elsewhere on the Internet that using @Inject instead of @EJB should be one fix. Peter "notes" that "we can use" @Inject but it smells fishy, as if he never got @EJB to work at all and now tries to flee responsibility.

Well, whatever the reason ("bug" or "consequence of the specification"), I couldn't get my dependency injection to work whatever vivid mix of annotations I used on the endpoint class itself or on the instance field.

### The ultimate fix

Is to programmatically use a JNDI lookup, but it looks ugly and should be avoided.

Comment: Hi Martin, have you seen Tyrus CDI sample/test? (https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/tree/master/samples/cdi). It is basically list what you can do with current implementation. We are always open for new test cases, but there are some issues with the spec itself - standard Request scopes don't work for WebSocket runtime, because it handles messages outside of servlets service/doFilter methods. See https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC-196 and https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC-197

Comment: @PavelBucek that comment seems like a good answer

Comment: In a similar situation using glassfish 4.0, I got my injected bean working by adding `@Stateless` next to `@ServerEndPoint`.  `@Named` did not work.  On my injected bean, both `@EJB` or `@Inject` worked.  I guess this won't help you since you tried it already.  But thanks to you since one of your suggestions did work for me.

Comment: @Toto2 I tested it on my Glassfish 4.0 installation as well.  As you said the suggestion worked.  I wonder if annotating it as @ Stateless is the right thing to do though.

Comment: Long time since for me. There's no point in making the WebSocket class into a fully featured EJB. What if you annotate the class `@ManagedBean`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(just restating what I wrote into comment to get this question from "unanswered" list)

You should checkou out [Tyrus CDI sample/test](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/tyrus/tree/master/samples/cdi).

It demonstrates list what you can do with current implementation. We are always open for new test cases, but there are some issues with the spec itself - standard Request scopes don't work for WebSocket runtime, because it handles messages outside of servlets service/doFilter methods. See [WEBSOCKET_SPEC-196](https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC-196) and [WEBSOCKET_SPEC-197](https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC-197).

Answer (score 2):

For me. annoting the websocket with @Stateful and EJB object declaration with @EJB did the work.

```
@Stateful
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/profileregistration")
public class ProfileRegistrationEndpoint {


@EJB
private ProfileRegistration profileRegEJB;
....
}
```

Comment: Could add your code of `ProfileRegistration ` or just say what annotations you use? and which version of Java EE you use?

Comment: Use Java EE 8, i cannot provide the whole code because of privacy issue.

Comment: so just annotations

Comment: @Stateful for making the server websocket a stateful ejb
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/profileregistration") for defining the class as a websocket server with the value attribute which is used by the websocket client

Comment: @Stateful in the server websocket was sufficient for me: now the injected Singleton is not null and i can use it. Tested on Wildfly 9, jdk 8