# Java EE 6 TomEE 1.7.2: How does one associate a websocket with a user's session?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, cdi, java-ee-6, apache-tomee

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/blah")
public class LeadChangeWebsocketEndpoint {
    @Inject
    private SessionScopedBean bean;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        bean.takeWebsocketAndDoSomething(session);
    }
    //....
}
```

That code results in an exception. How does one associate a websocket with a user's session? I can't find any documentation explicitly stating what the CDI scope of a  `@ServerEndpoint` bean is, even though it is capable of receiving CDI injections.

Comment: Before `onOpen` is called, the HTTP request is still alive with all it's cookies, tokens etc'. That's the time to authenticate the user or refuse the connection... especially as (on some servers) the `onMessage` callback might be called while `onOpen` is still processing... I'm not much into Java, so I'm not sure how you would apply this (I can show you in Ruby, but that won't help much).

Comment: It looks like it is not so well supported. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049387/using-a-cdi-sessionscoped-bean-from-a-websocket-serverendpoint
Did you try to annotated your class with @Stateless. Maybe this one could work.

Comment: Yikes... I'll see if I can get the Java EE expert group to take a look at that and clarify. I didn't try it as an EJB though, seems scary haha. I'll post the results for TomEE

Comment: @exabrial you forgot the result

Comment: You won't like it, it's not pretty... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888425/accessing-servletcontext-and-httpsession-in-onmessage-of-a-jsr-356-serverendpo